# MySQL join operation to get info about post along with name of user who wrote it

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. Joint queries are still a bit puzzling to me.

I have following tables:

```
users: id, name, password
posts: id, user_id, title, content, date
```

I'd like to get result like this:

```
title, content, user, date
```

I know I can get all data from the tables like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users, posts;
```

And than just use data from colums I want, but I've been trying unsuccessfully to make this cleaner. Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The set `SELECT * FROM users, posts` is called the _cartesian product_, and essentially is every user against every post - which in this case isn't very useful. You need to ensure the users.id is the same as posts.user_id, either via a `WHERE`, or via a `JOIN` as per Matthew's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a join and table aliases

```
select p.title, p.content, u.name, p.date
from posts p
join users u on u.id=p.user_id
```

If you don't want to use the join syntax, you can do the same with the cartesian product and use a where statement.

```
select p.title, p.content, u.name, p.date
from posts p, users u
where u.id=p.user_id
```

EDIT:
fixed some typos

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select title, content, user, date
from users u
inner join posts p
on u.id = p.user_id
```